# How can I parser a pcap file and read only some specific bits in python from the byte information in the pcap file?

Tags: python, pcap

```
+---------+---------------+----------+
09:28:21,957,743   ETHER
|0   |e8|b1|fc|14|91|73|58|ac|78|e3|a7|7f|08|00|45|48|00|54|50|81|00|00|79|11|04|9b|0a|04|17|aa|0a|42|c0|45|00|89|00|89|00|40|36|f9|d8|50|85|83|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|20|46|44|46|4a|46|44|46|45|45|46|45|4e|46|43|45|50|45|50|46|45|43|41|43|41|43|41|43|41|43|41|43|41|00|00|0a|00|01|00|00|00|00|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
09:28:21,968,617   ETHER
|0   |ff|ff|ff|ff|ff|ff|e8|b1|fc|14|91|73|08|00|45|00|00|4e|00|0c|00|00|80|11|95|ca|0a|42|c0|45|0a|42|cf|ff|00|89|00|89|00|3a|02|ce|d8|50|01|10|00|01|00|00|00|00|00|00|20|46|44|46|4a|46|44|46|45|45|46|45|4e|46|43|45|50|45|50|46|45|43|41|43|41|43|41|43|41|43|41|43|41|00|00|20|00|01|

+---------+---------------+----------+
09:28:21,987,353   ETHER
|0   |01|00|5e|00|00|fc|e8|b1|fc|14|91|73|08|00|45|00|00|38|5a|68|00|00|01|11|b3|c9|0a|42|c0|45|e0|00|00|fc|d7|fa|14|eb|00|24|98|2b|85|df|00|00|00|01|00|00|00|00|00|00|0a|73|79|73|74|65|6d|72|6f|6f|74|00|00|01|00|01|
```

Comment: You need to make an attempt at this first and if you encounter problems, you can post a question clearly explaining what you have tried and what error(s) you are getting.
But it is also equally important that you do some basic research before posting your question.

Comment: Actually I am new to Python. I had a C++ background before. Hence I am not able to find out what I need to do for this task. So if you could just point me in the right direction, it would be very helpful.